# Highcharts Polar Stacked Column chart - Legend is cut off

Tags: javascript, highcharts

the legend of my polar stacked column chart is cut off, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vz8nR/

How can i avoid this?

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [
        {
            name: 'someCategory #1',
            data: [12, 13, 14, 15, 5, 17]
        },
        {
            name: 'someCategory #2',
            data: [13, 15, 4, 12, 14, 16]
        },
        {
            name: 'someCategory #3',
            data: [1, 15, 13, 4, 14, 30]
        },
        {
            name: 'someCategory #4',
            data: [13, 15, 3, 12, 1, 16]
        }
    ],

    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'column',
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        plotBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        width: 275,
        height: 300
    },

    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['thisisalong name', 'yetanotherreallylong name', 'i dont even know what to write', 'hmletsthinkofsomething', 'stillnonamethought of', 'thisisthelastone'],
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        endOnTick: false,

        showLastLabel: true,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value + '%';
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%',
        followPointer: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            shadow: false,
            groupPadding: 0,
            pointPlacement: 'on'

        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Flow control of text in SVG:s are difficult. Increasing the with of the graph and `#container` would help. However this might not be possible in the design.

So if that is not possible I would use javascript to split the words with the `formater` function. That is check each word, if it's to long split the word. That is `alongword` becomes `along- word`.

There is also another hack that can be done and that is to set `useHTML: true` and inject a space character in the strings that are to long. However, this can mess up the formatting.

Here is an example when that is done.
http://jsfiddle.net/vz8nR/1/